# Pass input file to python debugger in Aptana

Tags: python, debugging, aptana

How can I pass an input file to a Python script in Aptana python debugger? 
From console I do something like:

> python test.py < input.txt

I tried editing the debug configuration in order to add the input file as 
program arguments, but it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Aptana can handle this. If not, just override `sys.stdin` in test.py:

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r')
```